# How to subtract input std_vector with local variable integer?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have this input vector that i have to subtract from my internal variable

```
entity f11 is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
             ANIMATE : in  STD_LOGIC;
             MAKE : in STD_LOGIC;
             X_vga : in STD_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
             Y_vga : in STD_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
             X_pos : out STD_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
             Y_pos : out STD_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
          VALID : out STD_LOGIC
      );
end f11;

architecture basic of f11 is

TYPE data_out IS ARRAY(0 TO 5) OF std_logic; 
TYPE mem_data IS ARRAY(0 TO 6) OF data_out; 
SIGNAL ALIVE : STD_LOGIC := '0';
variable f11_data : mem_data := (
        ( '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'),
          ( '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1'),
          ( '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0'),
          ( '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1'),
          ( '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0'),
          ( '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1'),
          ( '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0')
          );

variable pos_x : integer := 8;  
variable pos_y : integer := 8;  


variable xvga : integer ;  
variable yvga : integer ;  
process(CLK) 
 begin
    if(rising_edge(CLK)) then
        xvga:= to_integer(unsigned(X_vga));
        yvga:= to_integer(unsigned(Y_vga));
        if(MAKE = '1')then ALIVE <= MAKE;end if;
        if( xvga <= pos_x + 5 and  yvga <= pos_y + 6 ) then 
        VALID <= f11_data ( xvga - pos_x )(xvga - pos_y) and ALIVE ;
        end if;
    end if;


end process;


X_pos <= pos_x;
 Y_pos <= pos_y;

end basic;
```

It keeps giving me an error that

```
Error (10482): VHDL error at f11.vhd(53): object "to_integer" is used but not declared
```

and I really don't know how to get around this problem or is there any other way for me to subtract these two values, is there some reference material that i can look into couse I'm really new to this stuff, THANKS !

Comment: Besides a missing context clause in your **52** lines (`library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;` and `use ieee.numeric_std.all;` the error message relates to there are other errors. A variable (other than a shared variable prior to -2002) cannot be declared as a block declarative item, 5 occurrences. The architecture is missing the reserved word `begin` after the last block declarative item.  You need to convert pos_x and pos_y to std_logic_vector in assigning to x_pos and y_pos (e.g. `x_pos <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(pos_x, x_pos'length));` Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hey man, I edited my question could take another look at it ?
Also thanks for sugestion !!

Comment: @BalsaPopovic your edits so drastically change the question that you're no longer asking the same thing. You should revert that edit. If you have a new question, post a new question. When you do ask that new question, be sure to be clear about what you're asking. In the question's current state, I have no idea what your **Question** is.

Comment: yeah man, sorry. It's just that i can't post another question till tomorrow so I tried to put it in this one. I'll try to rephrase it and post it again thanks anyway ! @KevinKruse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `numeric_std` from the `IEEE` library to use `to_integer`.

Add this to the top of your file:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
```

Comment: Hey man I made some edits to the original question, I would be very thankful if you could take another look at this .
Thanks for the reply anyway !!